# Possibility of odd product in Java array. No output

Tags: java, arrays

HI I wish to check whether there is an odd product among two elements in a given input array .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddProduct {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int A[] = new int[10];
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            A[i] = s.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if ((A[i] * A[j] / 2) == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Odd product :" + A[i] * A[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is running but no output is displayed for the following input :
3 5 7 11 13 19 23  25 9. Where did it went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
A[i] * A[j] / 2 == 1
```

to:

```
A[i] * A[j] % 2 == 1
```

Comment: ok, yes change required ,, but no output on updated execution.

Comment: I changed..but no output for the given numbers.

Comment: Do "javac OddProduct.java" and then "java OddProduct" and then "3 5 7 11 13 19 23 25 9 11"